# Poner fotos seguidas

Tags: diseño

Estoy haciendo una página web para mi pfc el caso esta en que haciendo el html y el css consegui que unas imagenes se pusieran en una misma fila con su correspondiente titulo debajo, sin embargo ahora al implementarle el php se me han bajado, es decir estan una debajo de la otra. El caso es que queria ponerlas como las tenia antes, porque creo que esteticamente queda mejor. Adjunto el codigo del php/html con el css:

index.php

```
<section id="blog">
      <h3>Lo ultimo de nuestro blog</h3>
      <?php
      $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','smn');
      $sql="SELECT * from contenido";//seleccionamos todos os campos da equipo_aluguer
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);//gardamos o resultado unha variable
        while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         ?>
      <div class="contenedor">
        <article>
          <img src="<?php echo $mostrar['imagen'] ?>">
          <h4><?php echo $mostrar['titulo'] ?></h4>
        </article>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </section>
```

CSS.

```
#blog h3, h4 {
  text-align: center;
}

#blog .contenedor{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#blog article{
  margin: 15px;
}

#blog img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 280px;
}
```

Comment: probaste darle el display: flex y el justify-content-center a la etiqueta <article>??? en tu css veo que tienes así #blog .contenedor{...} ajustalo así #blog .contenedor article